# BlackBerry - Access Personal Information request while the app asks for Recording permission

Tags: blackberry, permissions

In my BlackBerry app, I invoke a permission request for RECORDING feature
for the app when it is first launched.
It works fine with BlackBerry Storm.
However, when I install and run the app on BlackBerry Torch, after the app asked permission for Recording, it popups a dialog box about **Application Permission Request** as follow:

`Some applications do not function properly unless they are given the permission they request; however, allowing applications the following permissions may impact your privacy, security, or cost.`

**Personal Information**
This includes content such as your email address, contact information, audio files, video files, and other saved files. Some application might share your personal information with third parties.

There is only a button "Save" for this dialog box.
The app DOES NOT collect user information. Do you know why users have this Personal Information message? How to disable this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is an OS6 change. Like you said, I've noticed it on the Torch but not other devices. (Storm is OS5.)

Since you're asking for recording permissions you could be recording the user without their explicit knowledge. So it is personal information in that sense.

I think RIM has decided to change the user-facing disclaimer about recording. I have an app that needs recording and it ran the same on 4.6, 4.7 and 5, but running the same code on 6 through up the prompt you described above.

Comment: Do you know how to not display it?